# Recreating Houdini Paint Smear in Blender using FLIP (Help!)

Tags: fluid-simulation

I saw this amazing Houdini tutorial[image] the other day and was wondering If I was able to recreate it using Blender.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TvAe3GxNFs&ab_channel=Entagma

My results, however, are less than satisfactory. I added a screen grab of what my result looks like.

I end up with weird tearing and floating bits. My Viscosity is set to 5 which is large, but according to this video, 5 looks about right to me (folding nicely like paint):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt2wjrm7pIs&ab_channel=BlenderRookie

What am I missing? My resolution is already set to 100 and I made sure to reduce the speed of the collider just in case that was causing any issues (although the collider has 16 sampling substeps which should be plenty).

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!